# Windows 10 "No Wi-Fi Networks Found" - using a new Wifi Adapter

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter

Wanting to move my desktop to my room; normally I use ethernet but at the moment that is not a valid option in my room.

Today I purchased a tp-link 300 Mbps Mini Wireless N USB Adapter (TL-WN823N)

The problem: I can't connect via Wi-Fi. When I open the menu I see a "No Wi-Fi Networks Found" message.

I've already spent many hours reading troubleshooting guides on the internet with no success.

- reinstalled driver from both the website and the provided disc
- updated driver through device manager
- restarted the computer and modem countless times.

and probably a few other things as well...

I'm fairly confident that the problem is with my computer not the driver. before I purchased this adapter I tried with an old/cheap adapter and it wasn't working either. although it did give different reasons for being unable to connect(such as "secured, no internet" "can't connect to this network" (I assumed it was at fault). I needed a new and better one anyway.

would anyone be able to help me resolve this issue so I can use my computer with a wireless connection

Thanks in advance!

let me know if there's any information I can provide to help flesh out the problem some more.

Update: still no success but maybe this will help.
when I typed "ipconfig /release" "ipconfig /renew" into cmd I got some feedback that may be useful.

No operation can be performed on Wi-Fi 2 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 16 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 17 while it has its media disconnected.

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 16:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 17:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

enter code here

Comment: Have you tried to clear all network prior configurations, in command line, e.g. "ipconfig /release", "ipconfig /renew", "ipconfig /flushdns"? Switching the Airplane mode on, then off after a minute or so, can do the trick too, because it basically powers off the network adapters. You can also try to boot in Safe Mode with network on, and see if you've still got the same problem. If not, it might be that a third-party (antivirus, firewall?) is preventing your WiFi adapter from accessing the available networks.

Comment: How do you know you have Wi-Fi reception where you are? How did you connect the Wi-Fi adapter to your PC? Directly in a front or back USB port?

Comment: Do you get a WiFi signal on your phone in the same location as the PC?

Comment: while testing my Adapter my PC was directly next to my modem (because the ethernet cable is plugged in currently). both my phone and university laptop have perfect connections both where my PC is now and where I will be moving it too.

Comment: also @Didier I tried Airplane, Safemode (however no wifi options were available so I might have done something wrong there) and did the ipconfig stuff you recommended.
also checked the firewall and it's checked as allowed- although maybe there's something else under a different name that isn't check?

Comment: Your adapter comes with WPS (WiFi Protected Set-up), which allows you to connect to any access point by pressing a button on it (the adapter). Have you tried that?

Comment: @JimmyTapner Does it work if you unplug the Ethernet cable?